# Live Statistics In O(1) space and time

Tags: algorithm, rest, caching, statistics

I recently submitted a code challenge for a job position.
It was supposed to post Transactions on a REST service as follows:

POST /transactions

```
{
   "amout" : "10.12"
   "timestamp" : "2018-09-25T12:00:00
}
```

and GET /statistics with a response as follows:

```
{
  "count" : "3"
  "min" : "100.00"
  "max" : "200.00"
  "sum" : "450.00"
  "avg" : "150.00"
}
```

The constrains are what make the solution hard, and they are:

1.- It should not use SQL to store the transactions, so it's basically an in memory transactions cache.

2.- It should always perform in O(1) for both time and aux space

3.- Scheduled cleanup is not enough.

4.- Only Transactions committed in the last 60 seconds from when the request is made should be taken into consideration for the statistics.

My first approach was to generate a wrapper for the statistics with the current server minute as an ID an every transaction or query updated the cache, but this fails cause it only process current minute transactions, dismissing transactions within 60 secs but from previous minute.

All other approaches I came up with required some sort of iteration which violated the O(1) constraint in time, at the end I got rejected, but I want to learn from the community what would've been the best approach.

Cheers

Comment: What does the `count:3` mean? Stat are calculated considering last 3 transactions?!

Comment: @AnandUndavia it means that in the last 60 secs, 3 transactions were made, and all other values are calculated base on the same rule

Comment: Alright and what do you mean by the last point *Scheduled cleanup is not enough*?

Comment: @AnandUndavia since the statistics are dynamical depending on which second you ask for them, having a cron task that removes the old transactions from the data structure holding them is not a correct solution

Comment: And about the `timestamp` field would it always be starting of a minute or it can be anything?  Like Would it be only `2018-09-25T12:00:00` or `2018-09-25T13:00:00` or we can have some `2018-09-25T12:00:32` or `2018-09-25T12:00:12` and so on

Comment: @AnandUndavia it should always be posted within the last 60 secs if older, just respond with HTTP status code 204 but dismissed and if its a date in the future throw an error

Comment: I posted the answer, I also recommend you to update the question involving all these details you mentioned in the comments

Comment: Seems like the time stamps only have 1 second resolution, so you can keep statistics for each one second interval. When a GET request is processed, you need to combine the statistics from 60 intervals. But O(60) and O(1) are the same thing as far as big-O is concerned. In other words, if you processed 10 million POST transactions while keeping only 60 sets of statistics, then you've met the O(1) space and time requirements. Which is to say that some iteration is allowed, as long as the number of iterations doesn't depend on the number of transactions.

Comment: @user3386109 That seems very reasonable, having a map the the hour-min-sec as key and statistics values as object value, so when iterating only calculates a key and loops 60 times.
If you post the answer I'lld gladly upvote it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Seems like the time stamps only have 1 second resolution, so you can keep statistics for each one second interval. When a GET request is processed, you need to combine the statistics from 60 intervals.

But O(60) and O(1) are the same thing as far as big-O is concerned. In other words, if you processed 10 million POST transactions while keeping only 60 sets of statistics, then you've met the O(1) space and time requirements. Which is to say that some iteration is allowed, as long as the number of iterations doesn't depend on the number of transactions.

Mapping each hour-minute-second to a statistics object allows the GET request to be processed with at most 60 iterations, regardless of the number of POST transactions that were received.

Comment: `My first approach was to generate a wrapper for the statistics with the current server minute as an ID` - the OP was so close :) (+1)